# Combine two tables with multiple rows in a date show into one row in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to combine two tables into a single result set. I need to iterate all the single row from the give date.

This is table one showing single row:

```
  SELECT 
      [sid], [ecode], [scty] ,[sonm]
  FROM 
      [Z_ALI].[dbo].[M_STORE] 
  WHERE
      [sonm] = 'PENZKI STORE'
```

Result:

```
  sid     ecode        scty            sonm
 -----------------------------------------------
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE
```

This is table two showing the date:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '9/1/2019' 
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '12/31/2019' 
DECLARE @dayOfWeek INT = 2;

WITH cte_Recursion AS
(
     SELECT @startDate AS [Date] 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
     FROM cte_Recursion 
     WHERE [Date] < @endDate
)
SELECT [Date] 
FROM cte_Recursion 
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) = @dayOfWeek 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Result:

```
  Date
  ------------------------
  2019-09-02 00:00:00.000
  2019-09-09 00:00:00.000
  2019-09-16 00:00:00.000
  2019-09-23 00:00:00.000
  2019-09-30 00:00:00.000
  2019-10-07 00:00:00.000
  2019-10-14 00:00:00.000
  2019-10-21 00:00:00.000
  2019-10-28 00:00:00.000
  2019-11-04 00:00:00.000
  2019-11-11 00:00:00.000
  2019-11-18 00:00:00.000
  2019-11-25 00:00:00.000
  2019-12-02 00:00:00.000
  2019-12-09 00:00:00.000
  2019-12-16 00:00:00.000
  2019-12-23 00:00:00.000
  2019-12-30 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get the output like this:

```
  sid     ecode        scty            sonm         Date
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-09-02 
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-09-09
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-09-16
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-09-23
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-09-30
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-10-07
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-10-14
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-10-21
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-10-28
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-11-04
  1    LAG-SNP-01   San Pablo City  PENZKI STORE  2019-11-11
  etc
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a simple `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: yes sir i need to combine two tables in that two query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired results by doing a `CROSS JOIN` as

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 'LAG-SNP-01', 'San Pablo City',  'PENZKI STORE')
) T(sid, ecode, scty, sonm)
CROSS JOIN
(
  VALUES
  ('2019-09-02 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-09-09 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-09-16 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-09-23 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-09-30 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-10-07 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-10-14 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-10-21 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-10-28 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-11-04 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-11-11 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-11-18 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-11-25 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-12-02 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-12-09 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-12-16 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-12-23 00:00:00.000'),
  ('2019-12-30 00:00:00.000')
) TT(Date)
```

Which is similar to

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '9/1/2019' 
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '12/31/2019' 
DECLARE @dayOfWeek INT = 2;
DECLARE @T TABLE(ADate DATE);

WITH cte_Recursion AS
(
     SELECT @startDate AS [Date] 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
     FROM cte_Recursion 
     WHERE [Date] < @endDate
)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT [Date] 
FROM cte_Recursion 
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) = @dayOfWeek 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      [sid], [ecode], [scty] ,[sonm]
  FROM 
      [Z_ALI].[dbo].[M_STORE] 
  WHERE
      [sonm] = 'PENZKI STORE' 
) T
CROSS JOIN @T TT;
```

Comment: I need to combine two query

Comment: Error occured in Option

Answer (score 0):

You don't need temporary tables.  Just use CTEs:

```
WITH dates AS (
      SELECT @startDate AS [Date] 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
      FROM dates 
      WHERE [Date] < @endDate
     )
SELECT s.[sid], s.[ecode], s.[scty], s.[sonm], d.[Date] 
FROM  [Z_ALI].[dbo].[M_STORE] s CROSS JOIN
      dates d
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.[Date]) = @dayOfWeek AND
      s.[sonm] = 'PENZKI STORE' 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

You could make this more efficient by just starting on the right date in the CTE and incrementing by 7 days instead of 1.